# Run a command with encrypted credentials

Tags: powershell-3.0

I would like to run a few cmdlets in the below script with encrypted credentials

```
Import-Module Remotedesktop
$SPAdmin = "domain\username"
$File = "\\myserver\Rduserlogoff\Securestring.txt"
[Byte[]] $key = (1..16)
$Password = Get-Content $File | ConvertTo-SecureString -Key $key
$Credential = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $SPAdmin, $Password 
$Username = Read-host "Enter the user name you wish to logoff"
$Broker = Get-connectionbrokerhighavailability -connectionbroker "brokerserver"
$Acbroker = $Broker.Activemanagementserver
write-host $username
$sessiondetails=@(Get-RDusersession -connectionbroker "$Acbroker" | where-object {$_.username -match $username} | Invoke-RDUserLogoff)
```

`$Broker` and `$sessiondetails` should be run with encrypted credentials. How to achieve it?

Comment: Sorry but What is the question?

Comment: $Broker and $sessiondetails lines should be run with encrypted credentials stored in $credential object. Some users don't have rights to run those using their credentials. they need elevated creds stored in $credential.

Comment: @Raghava With the password file and the key from the script anyone could easily decrypt the encrypted password. Don't do this. Ever.

Comment: Okay, this script is run internally and that account has limited access. For now that is the only we have with us to run it. May I know how to run those lines with cred stored in $credential

Comment: I'm not going to help you shoot yourself in the foot. NEVER store/use admin credentials like this. Period.

Comment: @Ansgar, sure but at least for getting an idea on how to do it.